# Imagens no BD MySQL na linguagem java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, netbeans, tabela-banco-de-dados

Iqeria saber como insere imagens no banco de dados para que quando eu possa pesquisar apareça a imagem e os dados dela.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode criar um tabela no seu banco de dado com as seguintes colunas:

tabela: arquivo
colunas: length (integer), content_type (character varying), id (integer), content (bytea), nome (character varying);

Na tua classe java você teria:

private String nome;
private String contentType;
private long length;
private InputStream content;

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma classe com propriedade de array de bytes.

Vou exemplificar uma forma utilizando Spring Boot com JPA:

Primeiro, criamos a classe que representa o modelo no banco de dados. O @Lob representa o tipo blob no banco, onde serão armazenados bytes da imagem.

```
@Entity
public class Document {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Lob
    private byte[] content;

    //get e set omitidos
}
```

Com isso, basta persistir no banco, com Spring Data, seria algo assim:

```
documentRepository.save(document);
```